# How do i use enums saved in my db on my React-Redux client side?

Tags: reactjs, redux, enums, react-redux

I have many enums in my database, exposed as an API through GraphQL.

My React-Redux client uses the enums in many components - My question is:

I want my enums to be available in some way on the client side. How would you implement that?

I thought of a few solutions:

1. EnumsReducer - load the enums to a reducer and pass to every component through react-redux's connect. I didnt like this option because it requires a lot of boilerplate.
2. Static class - create an EnumsService with methods that fetch the enums from the server and every component that needs enums will import the EnumsService and use the enums it needs.

What do you think?